# Вопрос по красно-черному дереву?

Tags: дерево, бинарное-дерево

Возможно ли такое красно-черное дерево?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня интересует возможна ли вот эта фиолетовая замкнутая область:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

-ведь баланс "детей" тут вроде бы ни нарушается - черные листья дают по два сына каждый - и один сын при этом у них общий? и получается вот такая замкнутая область - которая внешне выглядит как вершина с тремя связями но на самом деле, если посмотреть от каких вершин идут эти связи, то получается, что баланс все равно не нарушается - каждая вершина имеет по два сына.
*Вот в чем мой вопрос:* я хотел узнать - дают ли какие либо преимущества такие вот замкнутые фрагменты структур на деревьях поиска и красно-черном дереве в частности в плане учетной стоимости поиска по дереву?
 Т.е если образуется замкнутая структура в дереве, то при поиске по нему за эту структуру можно "платить " - меньше - ведь ее вершины соединены как в замкнутом графе и по идее и учетная стоимость поиска -должна быть меньше?

Comment: Нет, не теория- просто я подумал что если образуется замкнутая структура в дереве, то при поиске по нему за эту структуру можно "платить " - меньше - ведь ее вершины соединены как в замкнутом графе и по идее и учетная стоимость поиска -должна быть меньше. вот и решил спросить может кто знает - прав я или это бред.

Comment: А изображение с разноцветными ребрами привел для наглядности,что бы было видно, что к вершине - образующей замкнутую структуру(тут она красная  - для соблюдения баланса длины черных листьев) идет две родительские ветки и сама она также дает две ветки - т.е баланс бинарного дерева соблюдается, хотя со стороны выглядит как будто у вершины три связи.

Comment: В бинарном дереве емнип узел не может иметь более 3 связей (одна от родителя и две к детям). Так что узлы с 4 и более связями и бинарное дерево несовместимы...

Comment: Но ведь в красно черном дереве - от родителя идет по две связи

Comment: Тем более что к красной точке в треугольнике и идет одна связь от родителя - оранжевая и от самой точки - две к детям - зеленые. Просто Так получается что одна зеленая и одна оранжевая связь сходятся в дочернем черном листе и получается замкнутая структура.
Но сама красная вершина имеет не более 3 связей

Comment: То есть чёрных узлов с 4 и 5 связями Вы на своих картинках в упор не видите?

Comment: Все, я понял о чем Вы . извините.

Comment: А вообще откуда ноги-то растут у описываемого интереса? потому как он старательно наводит на мысль о бинарном дереве, каждый узел которого является бинарным деревом...

Comment: Ноги растут от курсов издательства Яндекса - только начал учить деревья поиска.  А вот про такое дерево  - узлом которого является другое дерево - еще не слышал. Спасибо, ознакомлюсь.